# DB2: [Error Code: -802, SQL State: 22023] [SQL0802]

Tags: db2, decimal

Error translated from Portuguese to English: "Error data conversion or data format conversion."

I have created a view:

```
MNUM DECIMAL 8,0                                


create view db.abc as select * from x where decimal(SUBSTR(MNUM, 2,6), 6, 0) = 57092
```

the mnum looks like 1057092 in this example, SUBSTR(MNUM, 2,6)=057092 and decimal(SUBSTR(MNUM, 2,6), 6, 0) should be = 57092 but throws that error!

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MOD function to get a part of the number instead of struggling with the char and numeric operations

```
select decimal(SUBSTR(12345678, 2,6), 6, 0)
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
--returns 234567

select mod(12345678 / 10, 1000000)
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
--returns 234567
```

They return the same result, but the last one can be applied for number operations only. And, if you wat to secure your number to a decimal with 6 places, you can do this (if your DB2 version allows it):

```
select digits(dec(mod(12345678 / 10, 1000000), 6))
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Just to be sure that your operation can work, you should evaluate if the MNUM value is not null:

```
digits(dec(mod(COALESCE(MNUM, 0) / 10, 1000000), 6))
```

Comment: thanks that worked (some tweaks)! decimal(mod(mnum, 1000000), 6, 0) = 56029, and now how do I get the first char with the mod method?

Comment: ups, I forget to mention, the numbers can start with number 2 too :s

Answer (score 0):

The SUBSTR function works on a string, not a decimal number.

I don't know which version of DB2 you're using, but you can try this:

```
DECIMAL(SUBSTR(CAST(MNUM AS CHAR(10)), 2, 6), 6, 0)
```

The "10" includes 8 characters for the number, 1 for the decimal point, and 1 for the sign.

Comment: if I use substr on a decimal it works correct, SUBSTR(MNUM, 2,6)=057092, but the next step is the problem. Anyway with your code the error is the same :s

Comment: even this: DECIMAL(SUBSTR(CAST(MNUM AS CHAR(10)), 2, 6), 6, 0)=DECIMAL(SUBSTR(CAST(MNUM AS CHAR(10)), 2, 6), 6, 0) returns the same error..

Comment: If all you want is a number to compare, try the INTEGER function instead of DECIMAL.

Comment: cast(SUBSTR(MNUM, 2, 6) as numeric(6,0))=55357 it's an error too..  :S

Comment: I have no more ideas.  Your error is a conversion error, so one of your data conversions from decimal to string to substring and back to decimal is not recognized by DB2.

Comment: but if I put what you said and what I have in my question shows the expected result.. only in the where query, comparing to a integer throws up this error..